# Can electric field lines form close loops in EM?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, gauss-law, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

I was reading on wikipedia about [electric field lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line#cite_note-lieb-3)

In the Precise definition part it says it can form close loops  but Kelvin–Stokes theorem it's written it  cannot be closed loops. (My teacher too told me that they never form close loops) Please point out Where I'm being wrong?

I am asking about when can they form close loops? That question states Why can't electrostatic field lines form closed loops?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't electrostatic field lines form closed loops?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105592/)

Comment: This question is asking about electric field lines generally rather than just the electrostatic case and therefore isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed loop of $\bf E$ never happens in static problems. But in dynamic problems you can get closed loops of $\bf E$. The standard case is a region of space where there is a steadily increasing magnetic field. The electric field in this situation is in loops around the region where $\bf B$ is increasing, in a similar pattern to the one you see for $\bf B$ around a current-carrying wire.

To prove the above one can use Maxwell's equations, which are differential equations for these vector fields, but I am assuming you don't want that level of mathematical detail.

Answer (score 0):

The field being talked about is the non-conservative ,  i.e. , induced electric field not the typical one constructed by a point charge or the static charge. The induced electric field follows from the theory of electromagnetic induction. Please check out  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction  for more insight. Thanks!